# Woocommerce filters in custom sidebar in custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can everyone help me?

I can't get why if I create my own template in WordPress for woocommerce like `page-index.php`, my filters don't appear(work) with my shortcode? (but other widgets like calendar work) And in shop page filter widgets are works.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: Page-index
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[products]' ); ?>
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
get_footer();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sidebar use this code.
put your template  woocommerce/template.

`<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );  ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce filters works on woo pages only (shop & product taxonomy).

[image]